# How to call a python script using tensorflow from Php web server

Tags: php, linux, python-2.7, tensorflow

I am trying to execute a python script from a php script. The python script named main.py calls many others python scripts including some special libraries like tensorflow for machine learning.

I am able to launch simple python scripts with just some print('hello') using exec, system or even popen, but the problem is when I try to execute my main.py
I already gave all the permissions to all the users.
With a quick research I could find that the problem is about the fact that the browser can't find the library tensorflow.

If I launch my program from command line, it perfectly works, so does anyone know how I can tell my browser where to get the libraries ?

Thank you

Comment: As a way of troubleshooting, can you print the directory where python is installed from php?